Problema con funciones en flet y python
estoy empezando a usar python3.12.3 con flet para crear una pequeño programa que se ejecuta sobre linux:
import flet as ft
import datetime

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = 'Salida'
    page.window.width = 330
    page.window.height = 250
    page.window.center()
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.START

    def aceptar_click():
        print(edtFecha.value)

    def cancelar_click():
        page.window.destroy()

    lblFecha = ft.Text('Introduce la fecha', width=200, size=20)
    edtFecha = ft.TextField(value=datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), text_align=ft.TextAlign.LEFT, width=100)
    lblHora = ft.Text('Introduce la hora', width=200, size=20)
    edtHora = ft.TextField(value=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), text_align=ft.TextAlign.LEFT, width=100)
    chkPrueba = ft.Checkbox('Modo de prueba', False, ft.LabelPosition.LEFT, tristate=False)
    chkApagar = ft.Checkbox('Apagar el sistema', False, ft.LabelPosition.LEFT, tristate=False)
    btnAceptar = ft.Button('Aceptar', width=120, icon='done', on_click=aceptar_click())
    btnCancelar = ft.Button('Cancelar', width=120, icon='close', on_click=cancelar_click())

    page.add(
        ft.Column( [
                ft.Row([lblFecha,edtFecha,],alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.START,),
                ft.Row([lblHora,edtHora,],alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.START,),
                ft.Row([chkPrueba,], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.START,),
                ft.Row([chkApagar,], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.START,),
                ft.Row([btnAceptar, btnCancelar,], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,),
            ]
        )
    )

ft.app(main)

El problema es que, al ejecutarlo, las dos funciones aceptar_click() y cancelar_click() se ejecutan siempre, sí o sí, sin quedar a disposición de los botones correspondientes, por lo que al ejecutarlo (da igual en consola o directamente en pyCharm) primero muestra en pantalla la fecha y a continuación cierra el programa.
Si elimino las funciones y el on_click= de los botones funciona sin problemas.
Como observación, al ejecutarlo me devuelve la línea:
*** (flet:25157): WARNING *: 12:28:05.239: Attempted to set message handler on an FlBinaryMessenger without an engine
repetida dos veces

Eso ocurre porque le estás pasando como argumento on_click el objeto retornado por la función dado qu las estás ejecutando:
btnAceptar = ft.Button('Aceptar', ..., on_click=aceptar_click())
#                                                            ^^
#          Con los paréntesis estás llamando a la fucnión ___|

btnCancelar = ft.Button('Cancelar', ..., on_click=cancelar_click())
#                                                               ^^
#                                               Lo mismo aquí___|

Esa ejecución se produce durante la inicalización de la app al instanciar flet.Button, lo que ocurre al ejecutar el script, por eso se ejecutan ambas al inicio.
Ambas funciones retornan None que es el objeto por defecto retornado por toda función si no hay un return explícito. Por lo que de cara a la instancia tu código equivale a:
btnAceptar = ft.Button('Aceptar', ..., on_click=None)
btnCancelar = ft.Button('Cancelar',..., on_click=None)

Lo que deriva en que al hacer click en tus botones no ocurre absolutamente nada ya que no hay función que ejecutar. En tu caso la ejecución prematura de cancelar_click y la consecuente ejecución de  page.window.destroy() cierra la app nada más iniciar, por lo que no puedes comprobarlo.
Tus funciones son callbacks, la idea es que al hacer click en el botón flet ejecutará el objeto que le pasaste a on_click, por lo tanto debes pasar una referencia a la función en si misma, es decir, sin los paréntesis antes señalados.
Por otro lado, dichas funciones reciben como argumento el evento que a causado su llamada, aunque no lo uses luego en tu función, tus callbacks deben poder recibir ese argumento.
Con ello quedaría algo así:
def aceptar_click(_event):
    print(edtFecha.value)

def cancelar_click(_event):
    page.window.destroy()

# ...

btnAceptar = ft.Button('Aceptar', width=120, icon='done', on_click=aceptar_click)
btnCancelar = ft.Button('Cancelar', width=120, icon='close', on_click=cancelar_click)


Muchísimas gracias, llevaba un par de días atascado buscando información para solucionar el problema.
